# How do I make redstone repeaters work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have tried to have redstone repeaters, to keep my redstone chain going, but it doesn't work. How do I make it work and why dosen't it work?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you edit your question and add more information? A screenshot would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're using repeaters? Don't mistake them for compateraters or redstone torches.

Answer (score 10):

The first thing you want to do is make sure that the repeater is in range. A single redstone current travels 15 blocks, so as long as the repeater is placed within that range, it will work. Additionally, regardless of where the repeater is placed, it will emit a signal strength of 15 blocks.

Secondly, repeaters, when placed, have a "direction". This is indicated by an arrow on the plate:

[image: Redstone Direction]

If a repeater is placed in a direction that does not follow the direction of the redstone it cannot repeat the signal:

[image: Redstone Current]

Comment: Do note that regardless on the signal strength in, it always outputs 15 signal strength.

Answer (score 2):

1. First, make sure that the repeater is facing a wire (place the wire by putting redstone on the ground)
2. Then place the repeater in the correct direction. (example: if you put a wire facing east, put the repeater from east or west to work)
3. Check that you have a power source. If all else fails, make sure the whole wire is powered. Do this by powering the start and making sure the entire line is glowing. If not,try placing a repeater at the least glowing position of the wire.

Comment: This does not add anything that my answer has not already covered...

Comment: @Ben so? it still answers the question. It's a valid answer.

Comment: @Aequitas Duplicate answers aren't constructive. Ok, sure, if this added something I missed, fine. But the [common concensus](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/how-do-we-handle-duplicate-answers) is that they are not constructive.

Comment: @Ben it does though, it mentions the glowing of the wire, and that the wire diminishes in brightness and at that dim point is where you need to add the repeater, I think that's easier to do then to count 15 blocks, This answer also goes more in depth (in some areas), I personally also think that it looks better than your answer with those large pictures. It also mentions the initial power source, you can't repeat without some power to begin with. I don't think these two answers are similar at all

Comment: @Aequitas if you feel there is no issue, that's no problem. This is why we have a voting system :)